# How To Disable Sticky Edges via Command Line?

Tags: command-line, unity, compiz, window-manager

I know how to disable Sticky Edges via the Settings->Display UI, however, I want to be able to do it via command line or config file.

Does anyone know how to disable "sticky edges" via a command or config file?

Where does Ubuntu store the config option?

Answer (score 5):

The following command disables the sticky edges:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-capture-mouse false
```

And this one re-enables them:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-capture-mouse true
```

Comment: you don't happen to know what the equivalent would be using gsettings?

Comment: @myol, Here is `gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ launcher-capture-mouse false`

Comment: Neither the dconf nor the gsettings answers seem to work on Ubuntu 17.10. What would be an up-to-date equivalent and how does one find out?

Comment: Works! You need to run the both commands.

Answer (score 2):

It could be `/org/compiz/profiles/Default/plugins/core/active-plugins` key in dconf database:

1. To check open terminal, run `dconf watch /`
2. Open CompizConfig Settings Manager, try Enable and Disable required options. Watch for change in terminal.
3. Use command `dconf write KEY VALUE` to set needed settings

   ```
   dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/Default/plugins/core/active-plugins
   dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/Default/plugins/core/active-plugins <value>

   gsettings get org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/Default/plugins/core/ active-plugins 
   gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/Default/plugins/core/ active-plugins <value>
   ```

Reference: `man dconf`, if you want to see all possible options, try `dconf-editor`

Comment: you don't happen to know what the equivalent would be using gsettings?

Comment: @myol, updated but this was only for Ubuntu 12.04, check 
Sylvain Pineau's answer. For Ubuntu 14.04