# How to configure ccsm from the command line or a script?

Tags: command-line, unity, compiz, scripts

THE GENERAL PROBLEM:
I wish to change some settings of ccsm from the command line, or more precisely a script. I imagine there will be some arcane combination of gsettings or gconftool that does what I want and I'd be grateful to be pointed at where it is documented.

THE SPECIFIC PROBLEM:
The "new" (not so new any more) "feature" (ahem) that windows become maximized when I move them to near the edges of the screen drives me bananas. I have learnt I can disable that with this sequence:

run ccsm, then:

window management | grid | corners /edges | set all to "none"

I'd like to wrap this stuff up in a script that I can run automatically whenever I configure a new machine, instead of having to go clickety-click every time.

Comment: Similar: http://askubuntu.com/questions/192641/how-to-disable-sticky-edges-via-command-line?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

Go to a machine where you have set up a working configuration, and copy the file `~/.config/dconf/user` to a USB stick or whatever.

Now go to the client machine.  Rename `~/.config/dconf/user` to `~/.config/dconf/user-2016-06-16`, and paste the config file from your computer that's set up the way you want it into the same place on the new machine.

If it doesn't work or messes something up, just copy the backed up file back to it's original place, over-writing the new config file.

Comment: That would transfer much more configuration than he asks for, **possibly including private information**. Also, it would overwrite much of the local configuration. And it does not do what he needs if compiz is using file based configuration in `~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/Default.ini`.